# nodejs with mysql cannot query twice

Tags: mysql, node.js

```
var messages = [];
var senders = [];
db.query('select * from message where (sender_id=? and receiver_id = ?) or (sender_id=? and receiver_id = ?) order by created desc limit 0,5 ', [senderId, receiverId, receiverId, senderId])
    .on('result', function (data) {
        messages.push(data);
    })
    .on('end', function () {
        db.query('select name,thumb_file_name,user_id,thumbnail_width,thumbnail_height from users where user_id = ? ', senderId)
        .on('result', function (data) {
            senders.push(data);
        })
        .on('end', function () {
            console.log('messages',messages);
            console.log('users',senders);
            console.log('senderId',senderId);
            console.log('receiverId',receiverId);
            io.to(socketId).emit("message", {messages: messages, users: senders});
        });
    });
```

On local this can get messages and users but when it is on the server, it only queries once so the 'messages' is missing.

Comment: add one `.on('error', function(err)` callback, so you can track errors... I would assume that the operation is taking too long in the server, and the db connection is being closed.

Comment: I am using pool connection so I guest the node is connecting to the db. I just tired logging the error but no error was logged.